# Scipy interpolation of numpy large array fails when exceeding a certain number of elements

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to analyze data from a time series. I want to interpolate the original data and make them equally spaced in time, so i use scipy cubic splines for this. Everything is going ok until 10000 points (float numbers) but don't seem to work after this number of points . I have tried with 10001 points and interpolation fails. Is it a memory problem ? I am using Canopy (academic license).

```
# reading the timeseries and interpolating with cubic splines
# for creating  equally spaced in time data
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats.stats as st
from   scipy import interpolate
# Reading the timeseries data file as a two column ASCII file
data = np.loadtxt('cut.dat')
data_tot = np.loadtxt('mynrg.dat')
# creating the arrays of each observable
# 10000 has been set during my tests i want 65536 points
time = np.array(data[:10000,0]); 

heat_flux =np.array( data[:10000,1]);


#new time values equaly spaced
new_time_values = np.linspace(time[0], time[np.size(time)-1],endpoint=True,num = np.size(time));

# cubic spline interpolation
# plot original and interpolated data
spl_fit = interpolate.splrep(time , heat_flux, s =0 , k =3);
new_heat_flux = interpolate.splev(new_time_values, spl_fit, der=0);
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: Do you get an error message? If so, can you please post it (including stacktrace maybe)? If you don't get an error message, what happens instead?

Comment: I am plotting raw and interpolated data for comparison and of course when i have this issue interpolated data do not appear. Also i get an error message from a histogram i am trying to plot with the interpolated values. When i check the values of spl_fit heat flux (inside the function) appears to have Nan values while when i check they heat_flux array it is ok. All these start when i use 65536 points

Answer (score 0):

Spline fitting is a global process. Your splrep call tries to manipulate a 10000 by 10000 matrix. The underlying Fortran code plays some rather smart tricks, but still --- do you really need continuous differentiability? You might be better off using a piecewise polynomial interpolator (have a look at scipy.interpolate.PPoly and BPoly).